# Posting some html gave me 403 error

Tags: php, html, post

When i try to send using post method something like this for example:

```
 <meta charset="utf-8"><body id="p1" style="cursor: auto;
```

it gaves me error:
Forbidden Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

but without meta tag its works fine.

Can anyone tell me what could be wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Meta tags should be inside the head tag as I understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is characteristic of a web application firewall, such as [mod_security](https://www.modsecurity.org/), being enabled on your web hosting account. This module is attempting to detect and block requests which attempt to exploit your web site; unfortunately, it seems to have determined that the perfectly harmless requests you're using here are suspicious enough to block.

Depending on how your host has mod_security configured, there may be a way for you to disable either the offending filter, or all filtering altogether, for your web site. However, the details will differ from one web host to another; your best bet will be to contact their technical support for details. (Mentioning mod_security by name may help.)

Comment: That could be it. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

Well first off you forgot the " at the end style and your body tag is still open

Comment: That doesnt matter, it's just for testing.